# Encript and load file

Tags: java, load, bytecode, caesar-cipher

Please, help me to find a mistake.
I have a class file. I take a byte code of this class and encrypt it by Caesar cipher. I have several arguments of command prompt:

1. class file: which we encrypt,
2. class file: in which the output will transmit
3. key: the number which we add to every number of byte code of the
   first argument.

I want simply to encrypt the first argument with a zero key, output will transmit to second argument, and then I want to run a second file (second argument).

I compile:

```
javac Caesar.java
```

Run:

```
java Caesar HelloWorld.class Hello1.class 0
```

(attention - I use zero key, so, file shouldn't be changed)

And run the second file, And I see such mistake:

> julia@julia-Aspire-5680 ~/zagruzchik $ java Hello1    Exception in
>   thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello1 (wrong name:
>   HelloWorld)           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)          at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>             at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>             at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)           at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)            at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)            at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)            at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)            at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)             at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)             at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)             at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)

My source code:

```
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;

/**
encript by caesar chipher
*/
public class Caesar {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        if (args.length == 3)
        {
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("USAGE: java Caesar in out key");
            return;
        }
        try ( //class which will be ciphered
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(args[0])) {
                //in output will go encripted byte code of file
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
                //this is key
                int key = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
                int ch;

                //in cycle encript byte code
                while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
                    byte c = (byte)(ch + key);
                    out.write(c);
                }
            }
        catch(IOException exception)
        {
        }
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is currently incorrect with regards to your bracket usage. I've tried to format it, but this line was causing an issue and I wasn't sure where you're `{` was supposed to go:
`try ( //class which will be ciphered`

Answer (score 0):

Beside the way you want to encrypt the file there is a more fundamental issue.

> I want simply to encrypt the first argument with a zero key, output will transmit to second argument, and then I want to run a second file (second argument).

which manifests itself in this exception

```
$ java Hello1 
Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello1 (wrong name: HelloWorld)
```

A `class` name must be equal to the `*.class` file name. If your class name is `HelloWorld` it can only be used if it is stored in a class file with the name `HelloWorld.class`.

If you rename the file to `Hello1.class` it will not work, as you instruct the Java Virtual Machine to execute class `Hello1` but this class is not stored the file `Hello1.class`.